# OneSignal - Sending notifications with player IDs

Tags: push-notification, onesignal

Sending notifications with player IDs in onesignal has a limit of 2,000 entries(player IDs) per REST API call, so we have to send multiple notifications each time.
Is it possible to connect these notifications and get one unique ID for all of them?